# `Docker-compose` fails with `OSError` although `docker run` works

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have `centos7-python37` based image that runs perfectly with `docker run ...` command
but fails when I run it through `docker stack deploy ...` with `OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol`. More details below

I have a `Dockerfile` based on `centos7-python37` build like below

```
FROM recognai/python-37-centos:latest

COPY ./receive.py ./requirements.txt ./
RUN python3.7 -m pip install -r ./requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "-u", "receive.py"]
```

and `requirements.txt` contains

```
pika==1.2.1
pyyaml
```

and above `Dockerfile` runs a `receive.py` file with the following contents.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import pika
import json


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    json_body = json.loads(body)
    print("Received {}".format(json_body))


def main():
    connection_parameters = pika.URLParameters("amqp://guest:guest@some-rmq-host.com:5672/")
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(connection_parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue="some_queue", durable=True)
    channel.basic_consume(queue="some_queue",
                          auto_ack=True,
                          on_message_callback=callback)
    print(' [*] Waiting for Release migration messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
    try:
        channel.start_consuming()
    except pika.exceptions.StreamLostError:
        main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```

and I build the image with `docker build -t test_service:0.0.1 .`
and run it with

```
docker run \
  -e PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}" \
  test_service:0.0.1
```

this build and run works perfectly, it executes the `receive.py` and wait for messages to be consumed.

Unfortunately, I can not say the same when I create a service using `docker-compose.yml`. Below are its contents

```
version: "3"

services:
  test:
    image: test_service:0.0.1
    environment:
    - PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Above `docker-compose` file errors out with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "receive.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "receive.py", line 42, in main
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(connection_parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 445, in _create_connection
    ioloop.poll()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 579, in poll
    self._poller.poll()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 1203, in poll
    self._dispatch_fd_events(fd_event_map)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 907, in _dispatch_fd_events
    handler(fileno, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/selector_ioloop_adapter.py", line 394, in _on_reader_writer_fd_events
    callbacks.writer()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/diagnostic_utils.py", line 53, in log_exception_func_wrap
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/io_services_utils.py", line 353, in _on_writable
    self._report_completion(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/diagnostic_utils.py", line 53, in log_exception_func_wrap
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/io_services_utils.py", line 286, in _report_completion
    self._on_done(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/connection_workflow.py", line 378, in _on_tcp_connection_done
    AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError(exc))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/connection_workflow.py", line 298, in _report_completion_and_cleanup
    on_done(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/connection_workflow.py", line 863, in _on_connector_done
    self._try_next_resolved_address()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/connection_workflow.py", line 829, in _try_next_resolved_address
    on_done=self._on_connector_done)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/connection_workflow.py", line 172, in start
    self._sock = socket.socket(*self._addr_record[:3])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 151, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

I can see that the process is complaining about the `IPv6` but why it was working with `docker run ...`.
I am kind of stuck can appreciate any help.

Cheers,
DD

Comment: That `-e PYTHONPATH=...` option seems odd to me: that should be a default path, and the variable expansion means you're injecting a host path variable into the container.  Does deleting the Compose `environment:` block help at all?  Or if that environment variable really is required, can you set it in a Dockerfile `ENV` statement?